# Como ver mi pagina desde mi Servidor

Tags: nodejs, angular

Me gustaría partir aclarando que es mi primera vez trabajando con Angular y a sido un parto, pero no lo dejaré por eso, siento un deber para con las horas que e invertido en aprender...

Actualmente trabajo con angular 9 en un servidor centOS 8, tenemos el dominio y antes(cuando se trabajaba con HTML y CSS solamente) solo teníamos que colocar el index.html en la ruta var/www/html
pero ahora cree el proyecto en la misma ruta var/www/ llamado "html" de manera de prevenir cualquier tipo de problema.

instalé node , material, cdk, animations, hammerjs (si como típico noob llené de paquetes JS que ni si quiera se utilizar).

al lanzar el comando "ng serve" el servidor parte pero no se visualiza al momento de acceder a la url de la pagina, solo aparece esto:
[image: Solo muestra la configuracion del servidor en apache.]

Comment: Al ejecutar ng serve , angular crea un servidor local en el puerto 4200 , revisa la doc oficial [angular.io/cli](https://angular.io/cli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver este proceso necesita hacer varias cosas, a continuacion le voy a mostrar paso a paso como hacer deployment de un app Angular en un servidor Apache.

> 1. Duplique en proyecto completo en el servidor.
> 2. Instale las dependencias de su proyecto usando **npm install**.
> 3. Use el comando **ng build --prod** para crear el directorio de distribucion que por defecto tiene el nombre dist.
> 4. Cambie el directorio raiz de apache a **/var/www/html/dist**.
> 5. Active mod_rewrite, reinicie apache.
> 6. Cree el archivo .htaccess en la carpeta raiz y copie esto en el archivo.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Con esto espero haber ayudado a resolver su problema.

Suerte!!!

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad, la respuesta que necesitaba